# PhpStorm 8 jump to souce without closing commit changes

Tags: phpstorm

When I'm in the window commit changes I see my changes, sometimes I can't see the context in the window and I want to see the source code in the editor, when I press F4 the editor jumps to the source but the commit changes window is closed. So I lose the position where I was in my commit changes review process.

Is there a possibility to show the selected code in the editor without closing the commit changes window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just double-click on the filename, and an editable diff view will pop up on top of the "Commit Changes" dialog.  The ability to edit the file is especially helpful if you need to make some quick last-minute modifications.

Comment: yes, that works, sometimes the solution is just to easy ;-) , thanks